# Multiplayer join request

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center, multiplayer

I am working on a multiplayer iOS game which is going to be integrated with Game Center.
I wonder if it is possible to send invite to another player to join the game? I read documents which described how to join the match, but it my case gameplayer is not a match at all - it's just a world everybody can join. I probably could represent the world as a hosted match, but in that case I'm not satisfied with limit up to 16 players per a match.

Answer (score 0):

You can send invites only to your game-center friends. Also, I read somewhere that only games are allowed to use game-center features, and apps that violate this will be rejected.

Comment: Thanks. But I still wonder if it is possible to send invite to install and join the game, not just to play a match.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "join the game". Do you mean to install the app on their phones? If thats the case, even if you invite a friend via game-center that doesn't have the app installed, the invitation will take them directly to the your app on the App store